# How to combine Date periods in SQL and create a composite timeline

Tags: sql, oracle

In a oracle table for each family (unique id) can have several people (unique id) in different relationship for a date range. I would like to get a timeline created to obtain the FamilyType based on combinations of relationship for the time periods. An example is given below for a particular Family.

```
  P1|-----Head---------------------------------------|
           P2|--Partner--------------|
                    P3|---Child----------------------|
                              P4|---Child------------|

    |=Single=|=Couple=|=Family=======|=SingleParent==|
```

Table has columns
FamilyId, PersonId, Relationship, StartDate, EndDate

Each | is a date (no time portion). The data guarantees that on a given date
* there will always be one person who is Head.
* There can be 0 or 1 Partner.
* There can be 0 or n child.

The rules are
* If there is only a Head the FamilyType is Single
* If there is a Head and a Partner the FamilyType is Couple
* If there is a Head , a Partner and 1 or more Children the FamilyType is Family
* If there is a Head and 1 or more Children the FamilyType is SingleParent

People can join or leave from a family on any date.
And people can change relationships. So following scenarios are possible

```
P1|----------Head--------------------|
           P2|----partner------------|---Head--------|
                    P3|---Child----------------------|
                          P4|--Child-----------------|

    |=Single=|=Couple=|=Family=======|=SingleParent==|

P1|----------Head--------------------|
           P2|----partner------------|---Head--------|
                    P3|---Child----------------------|
                          P4|--Child-----------------|
                                   p5|---Partner-----|

    |=Single=|=Couple=|=Family=======================|
```

How can this be done using SQL in Oracle 11GR2 (working using SQL only and not using procedural code). I am trying to evaluate whether this is best done in SQL or C#. As a curiosity answer specific for SQL Server 2012 is also good to have.

The result should be rows with StartDate, EndDate and FamilyType.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
with family_ranges(familyid, min_start, max_end, curr_date)
  as (select familyid, 
             min(startdate), 
             max(enddate),
             to_number(to_char(min(startdate), 'j'))
       from family
      group by familyid
      union all
      select familyid, min_start, max_end, curr_date+1
       from family_ranges
       where curr_date < to_number(to_char(max_end,'j')))
select familyid, min(curr_date) fromdate, max(curr_date) todate, state
  from (select familyid, to_date(curr_date,'j') curr_date,
               case when head = 'Y' and partner = 'Y' and child = 'Y' then 'Family'
                when head = 'Y' and partner = 'Y' then 'Couple'
                when head = 'Y'  and child = 'Y' then 'SingleParent'
                when head = 'Y' then 'Single'
               end state
          from (select f.familyid, d.curr_date, f.relationship
                  from family_ranges d
                      inner join family f
                              on f.familyid = d.familyid
                            and to_date(d.curr_date,'j') between f.startdate and f.enddate)
         pivot (
           max('Y')
           for  relationship in ('Head' as head, 'Partner' as partner, 'Child' as child)
         ))
 group by familyid, state
 order by familyid, fromdate;
```

forgive the nonsense with the date->julian. it's to work round a bug with 11.2.0.1-3 where date arithmetic fails with factored subqueries.

the fatored subquery part gets us a list of dates that the family spans. From that we join it back to family to work out who was in the family on that day.

```
select f.familyid, d.curr_date, f.relationship
  from family_ranges d
      inner join family f
              on f.familyid = d.familyid
            and to_date(d.curr_date,'j') between f.startdate and f.enddate;
```

now we pivot this to get a simple Y/N list

```
SQL> with family_ranges(familyid, min_start, max_end, curr_date)
  2    as (select familyid,
  3               min(startdate),
  4               max(enddate),
  5               to_number(to_char(min(startdate), 'j'))
  6         from family
  7        group by familyid
  8        union all
  9        select familyid, min_start, max_end, curr_date+1
 10         from family_ranges
 11         where curr_date < to_number(to_char(max_end,'j')))
 12  select familyid, to_date(curr_date,'j') curr_date, head, partner, child
 13            from (select f.familyid, d.curr_date, f.relationship
 14                    from family_ranges d
 15                        inner join family f
 16                                on f.familyid = d.familyid
 17                              and to_date(d.curr_date,'j') between f.startdate and f.enddate)
 18           pivot (
 19             max('Y')
 20             for  relationship in ('Head' as head, 'Partner' as partner, 'Child' as child)
 21           );

  FAMILYID CURR_DATE H P C
---------- --------- - - -
         1 09-NOV-12 Y
         1 11-NOV-12 Y
         1 13-NOV-12 Y
         1 23-NOV-12 Y
         2 23-NOV-12 Y
         2 28-NOV-12 Y Y
         2 29-NOV-12 Y Y
         1 30-NOV-12 Y Y
         1 01-DEC-12 Y Y
         1 03-DEC-12 Y Y
         2 18-DEC-12 Y Y Y
         2 20-DEC-12 Y Y Y
```

then its a simple case to get your required string from the rules and a group by to get the date ranges.

```
SQL> with family_ranges(familyid, min_start, max_end, curr_date)
  2    as (select familyid,
  3               min(startdate),
  4               max(enddate),
  5               to_number(to_char(min(startdate), 'j'))
  6         from family
  7        group by familyid
  8        union all
  9        select familyid, min_start, max_end, curr_date+1
 10         from family_ranges
 11         where curr_date < to_number(to_char(max_end,'j')))
 12  select familyid, min(curr_date) fromdate, max(curr_date) todate, state
 13    from (select familyid, to_date(curr_date,'j') curr_date,
 14                 case when head = 'Y' and partner = 'Y' and child = 'Y' then 'Family'
 15                  when head = 'Y' and partner = 'Y' then 'Couple'
 16                  when head = 'Y'  and child = 'Y' then 'SingleParent'
 17                  when head = 'Y' then 'Single'
 18                 end state
 19            from (select f.familyid, d.curr_date, f.relationship
 20                    from family_ranges d
 21                        inner join family f
 22                                on f.familyid = d.familyid
 23                              and to_date(d.curr_date,'j') between f.startdate and f.enddate)
 24           pivot (
 25             max('Y')
 26             for  relationship in ('Head' as head, 'Partner' as partner, 'Child' as child)
 27           ))
 28   group by familyid, state
 29   order by familyid, fromdate;

  FAMILYID FROMDATE  TODATE    STATE
---------- --------- --------- ------------
         1 05-NOV-12 24-NOV-12 Single
         1 25-NOV-12 14-DEC-12 Couple
         1 15-DEC-12 24-JAN-13 Family
         1 25-JAN-13 13-FEB-13 SingleParent
         2 05-NOV-12 24-NOV-12 Single
         2 25-NOV-12 14-DEC-12 Couple
         2 15-DEC-12 13-FEB-13 Family
```

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/484b5/1

Comment: great answer. I think the OP could have easily start a bounty on the question of that complexity

Comment: Thanks for this answer, great. I am not a SQL expert and never could come with this. Do you have a reference to the date bug you mentioned.

Comment: @Pratik If you have oracle support, check bug `Bug 11840579  wrong results with recursive subquery factoring and dates`. also see this test fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/7907. note the date goes backwards instead of forwards? also the `cast(sysdate as date)` seems bizarre but if you remove it you get another error. its all really broken.